# Is there an analogue of the Mertens function for the generalised Riemann conjecture

Tags: characters, riemann-hypothesis

It is known that the Riemann conjecture is equivalent to 
$$M(x) = O(x^{\frac12+\epsilon}),$$
where M(x) is the Mertens function.

Does there exist an analogue to this equivalence for the generalized Riemann conjecture ? (say a generalized Mertens function defined somehow with characters, and an asymptotic behavior)

Comment: Sure $L(s,\chi)$ has no zeros for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ iff $\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n) \chi(n) = O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$. For other L-functions it works quite the same way (but this is special to them, see $\eta(s-1)$ whose series only converges for $\Re(s) > 1$)

Comment: do you have a source for this ?

Comment: The proof is the same as for $\zeta(s)$ and is quite similar to the PNT. Search about the PNT in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619762/what-are-the-equivalent-statements-of-grh-using-the-m%C3%B6bius-or-liouville-function/1628146#1628146

Comment: Yes, this completely answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: is there the equivalent of mobius and mertens function for Selberg zeta function ? and selberg formula ?